# Server 2003 Performance Counters for File Shares?

Tags: windows-server-2003, file-sharing, performance-monitoring, performance

I've got a disk with several different things going on.  I'd like to determine approximately how much of the disk activity is due to file sharing.  Is there a counter for this?

Also, and I may have been dreaming this, I seem to remember seeing some program that might allow me to monitor file activity of a particular folder within a share.  Ring any bells?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In reference to monitoring the activity of a folder:

You can use WMI (CIM_DataFile) to monitor a folder for any modifications using something similar to this as the query:

SELECT * FROM __InstanceOperationEvent WITHIN 1 WHERE TargetInstance ISA "CIM_DataFile" AND TargetInstance.Drive="C:" AND TargetInstance.Path="\Data"

Something like this:

```
' Full path to the folder to monitor
sPath = "\\localhost\c$\Scripts"
sComputer = split(sPath,"\")(2)
sDrive = split(sPath,"\")(3)
sDrive = REPLACE(sDrive, "$", ":")
sFolders = split(sPath,"$")(1)
sFolders = REPLACE(sFolders, "\", "\\") & "\\"

' Create our WMI instance
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & sComputer & "\root\cimv2")
' Begin monitoring
Set colMonitoredEvents = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery _
("SELECT * FROM __InstanceOperationEvent WITHIN 1 WHERE " _
& "TargetInstance ISA 'CIM_DataFile' AND " _
& "TargetInstance.Drive='" & sDrive & "' AND " _
& "TargetInstance.Path='" & sFolders & "'")

Wscript.Echo vbCrlf & Now & vbTab & _
"Begin Monitoring for a Folder Change Event..." & vbCrlf

Do
    Set objLatestEvent = colMonitoredEvents.NextEvent
    Select Case objLatestEvent.Path_.Class

        Case "__InstanceCreationEvent"
            WScript.Echo Now & vbTab & objLatestEvent.TargetInstance.FileName _
            & " was created" & vbCrlf

        Case "__InstanceDeletionEvent"
            WScript.Echo Now & vbTab & objLatestEvent.TargetInstance.FileName _
            & " was deleted" & vbCrlf

        Case "__InstanceOperationEvent"
            If objLatestEvent.TargetInstance.LastModified <> _
                objLatestEvent.PreviousInstance.LastModified then
                WScript.Echo Now & vbTab & objLatestEvent.TargetInstance.FileName _
                & " was modified" & vbCrlf
            End If

        IF objLatestEvent.TargetInstance.LastAccessed <> _
            objLatestEvent.PreviousInstance.LastAccessed then
            WScript.Echo Now & vbTab & objLatestEvent.TargetInstance.FileName _
            & " was accessed" & vbCrlf
        End If

    End Select
Loop

Set objWMIService = nothing
Set colMonitoredEvents = nothing
Set objLatestEvent = nothing
```

Comment: Thanks!  I also just realized that sysinternals' Process Montior can show me file operations and I can filter by path.  It's not too good for statistics though.